# FB believes I'm granting an achievement when I'm registering one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, achievements

I'm having a problem where my achievement code, which worked perfectly in my staging (sandboxed) environment, is failing in my production environment.

When I HTTP POST to 
[my app id]/achievements
with data

```
 - achievement=[url of achievement, lints fine]
 - display_order=101
 - access_token=[an app access token]
```

...I get the error:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3403) Achievement hasn't been registered for this application. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
```

Which is what is supposed to happen when you try to give a user an invalid achievement. I've verified that the endpoint I'm calling is my app id, not a userid, so I'm at a total loss as to what could be going wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that this was a bug on FB's side that affected our particular app's record in their database. I filed it. They reproduced, assigned, and fixed it. If you're seeing this same behavior, there's nothing you can do to fix it yourself - just file a bug via the Developer app. You might want to refer to [the bug I filed](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/191195290959103).